# Differential equation solutions are equal or finite

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y_{1}$ and $y_{1}$ be solutions of $y''+p(x)\ y'+q(x)\ y = r(x)$ on $[a,b]$, where $P,Q,R$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Prove that either $y_{1} =y_{2}$ or $\{ x\in [a,b]\ :\ y_{1}(x) = y_{2}(x)\}$  is finite.

It is known that there is a unique solution, so if $y_{1},y_{2}$ are both solutions, then by the Wronskian, $\frac{y'_{1}}{y_{1}}=\frac{y'_{2}}{y_{2}}$ or $\frac{y'_{1}}{y_{1}}\not=\frac{y'_{2}}{y_{2}}$. But how do proceed after this? Help!!

Answer (score 1):

$u=y_2-y_1$ solves $u''+pu'+q=0$. If the claim were false $u$ could be a non-zero function with infinitely many roots in $[a,b]$.

What do you know about infinite subsets in bounded intervals? What consequence does the limit point have for the derivative $u'$ in that point and thus the solution $u$, invoking uniqueness?

Comment: Can you please elaborate or show detailed working

Comment: No, because any more hints or steps would mean to completely solve this (elementary) homework task. Obviously, you start with "let $y_1,y_2$ be not identical and the set of intersection points infinite, then..."

Comment: But is my proof on identical  solution right

Comment: I see nothing that constitutes proof or an argument. And yes, the Wronskian determinant is zero at least once is equivalent that one solution is a multiple of the other, but that is only true for homogeneous equations, which the equation in your task is not.

Comment: Yes but every non homogeneous differential equation has a corresponding homogenous form